# How to add more than 65,535 columns in a data grid view in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Or is there any better suited 3rd party control for this purpose?

Comment: you expect >65,535 columns to be human readable?

Comment: I really find it hard to think of some valid reason to do so...

Comment: I would take a look at the design of the application rather than searching for a data grid view which supports that...

Comment: After about 100 columns, I think the data would dissolve into "white noise".

Comment: I have to display the vertices of a mesh, the vertex count _can_ go really high in rare cases.

Comment: @annakata: It's perfectly readable if you turn your monitor on its side :-)

Comment: If you're displaying a mesh, you might want to use a graphics library instead....grids are slow. I can't imagine how bad a grid with 65k+ columns would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know that [DevExpress XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) supports, in theory, Int32.MaxValue rows or columns in the grid. In this case, the limit is the system memory not the grid.

But do you really need to display so much data?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Dont do it!

Long answer: Change the FillWeight to 10 or less (default is 100). The limit you are reaching is due to the total FillWeight exceeding 64K x 100 (who knows why that is a limit).

Comment: Well, if you keep the default FillWeight, then the column limit is about 655, because ColumnCount x FillWeight < 65535! So, even if you change the FillWeight to minimum, which is 1, the maximum number of columns will be 65,535.

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual list (loads only the rows that are visible). I'm not sure that WinForms ListView  has a virtual mode but the WPF one does.

So create a WPF user control and set it up for VirtualMode = True and host that user control on your WinForms client with an ElementHost container.

Sorry I can't be more specific, I don't have the code to hand.

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

You're missing that the FillWeight variable takes a floating point number not an integer, so 0.5f or 0.01f would do (the latter would allow up to 6553500 columns in theory). Unfortunately, creation is very slow (at least for me, increasingly past around 1000 columns; 10,000 cols takes about 20 seconds). Perhaps the VirtualMode others have suggested is worth a shot.

For what it's worth, here is the code I use to create an x by y size table of empty cells. Perhaps someone can optimize the speed further:

```
private void createDGVcells(DataGridView dgv, int columns, int rows) {
    // Optimization:
    dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;  // Massive speed up if high column count
    dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;   // Apx. 75% speedup for high row count
    dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false; // Further 50% apx speedup when creating rows
    dgv.ReadOnly = true;            // Small apx. 50ms latency speedup?

    // First clear any existing cells, should they exist:
    if (dgv.DataSource != null) dgv.DataSource = null;
    else    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        dgv.Columns.Clear();
    }

    // Create the first row (the columns):
    DataGridViewColumn[] dgvc = new DataGridViewColumn[columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvc.Length; ++i)   {
        DataGridViewColumn dg = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dg.FillWeight = 0.1f; // Allows up to 655350 columns in theory
        dgvc[i] = dg;
    }
    dgv.Columns.AddRange(dgvc);

    // Add all the rows (very quick)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows - 1; j++) dgv.Rows.Add();

    // Optional to turn these back on
    dgv.ReadOnly = false;
    dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xceed's DataGrid for WPF can do this easily and uses both column and UI virtualization. Check out their live demo. You can populate the demo with as many columns and rows needed to test perf. http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html